# Missing partial modifier on declaration of type: Safe to delete TenantRegistrationModel.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I am using MVC 5 with Entity Framework hosted in Azure. After I add my database via an ADO Entity Framework item, generate my model, and try to publish my app, I get an error that the "TenantRegistrationModel.cs" has a "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'mymodel.Models.IssuingAuthorityKey'; another partial declaration of this type exists".

It is safe to delete TenantRegistrationModel.cs? since it has two empty classes?

Thanks,

K.

Comment: Probably, maybe not. Use source control, remove the file and see what happens. You know you can hit F5 to run an application without having to publish it first?

Comment: If I remove it I can publish it, but when I try to browse to my scaffolded page, it gives me an "An error occurred while processing your request". They may not be related, but not sure.

Comment: Neither am I, it could prove useful to investigate the source of that error.